# How do I use this weapon skin?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

There is a weapon skin I want to use in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive called Pulse. I cannot figure out how to add it to the game. It says "considered for use pending" if this helps.

Comment: This is the link if it helps.   http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=194762471

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Counter-Strike: Global Offensive's workshop works differently than most Steam workshops. You cannot simply browse to a file and add it to your game. Instead, the workshop is used to see items that maybe added to the game as drops or a part of a weapon case, or ones that have already been added.

Once you acquire the weapon ([that particular one is already in the game](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A730+pulse) and can be found by opening a [winter offensive weapon case](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Offensive_Weapon_Case)), you can use it by going to your inventory in-game and replacing your current weapon with the new one by right-clicking on it and choosing "Replace T", "Replace CT" or "Replace both".